# A multiple choice exam has 20 questions, each with 4 answers, only one is correct. The students are guessing the answers in an independent way.

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, variance, binomial-distribution

Correct answer = +5, incorrect answer = -1, unaswered = 0.
What are the expected value of the grades and their variance? What is the probabilty to get the same grade as the expected value?

The answers are: 10, 135, 0.2.
I tried binomic distrubiton: p = 0.125 (0.5 if the students choose to answer the question and 0.25 if they're right) and the grades range from 0 to 100, but I don't get the correct answers. I'm assuming it's not Continuous uniform distribution, since the E(X) doesn't match as well.

Thank you.

Comment: The question lacks information, I see you've assumed the students have a $0.5$ probability of deciding to answer each question, but that's not in the statement you've given.

Comment: @AnilCh to get $10, 135, 0.2$, you need to assume the students decide to answer all the questions

Comment: @Henry I know, but that means either the question is ill-posed because it lacks that relevant part, or that OP has not conveyed the original statement as it was. I think it's important to know where this information was lost.

Comment: You're right, it wasn't given in the original question, just an assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- based on the three desired official solutions, it seems that the students are answering every question, and picking answers at random
- so your binomial distribution for the number of correct answers should be $X\sim \text{Bin}(20, \frac14)$. All other answers, i.e. $20-X$, will be incorrect.
- You can find the expected value and  variance of $X$
- You can find the marks $M$ as a function of $X$
- From this you can find the expected value and  variance  of $M$
- You can find which value of $X$ would make $M=\mathbb E[M]$ and the probability of this X

Comment: I switched the $Y$ and $X$ in my answer, so that it is now in accordance with your answer.

Comment: @Henry I'm sorry, I don't understand how to find the expected value and variance of M just from the function. If X is the number of correct answers, then M(X) = 5X - Y, right? think you

Comment: @user88891  $M=5X-(20-X)=6X-20$.  If $Y=aZ+b$  then $E[Y]=aE[Z]+b$ and $\text{Var}(Y)=a^2 \text{Var}(Z)$

Answer (score 0):

For $i=1,\dots,20$ let $Y_i$ denote the score for question $i$.

Preassuming that the student gives an answer to question $i$ we find:$$\mathbb EY_i=\frac14\times5+\frac34\times(-1)=\frac12$$

Note that this is positive, so a student must be **out of his mind** if he does not answer questions. Let us assume not with good reason that the student answers every question.

For finding variance be aware that $X_i=\frac16Y_i+\frac16$ has Bernoulli distribution with parameter $p=\frac14$ and consequently $X=\sum_{i=1}^{20}X_i=\frac16X+\frac{10}3$ has binomial distribution with parameters $p=\frac14$ and $n=20$.

(Observe that $X$ actually equals the number of questions that are answered correctly)

So: $$\mathsf{Var}X=np(1-p)=\frac{15}4$$ and from that we conclude for $Y=6X-20$ that:  $$\mathsf{Var}(Y)=6^2\times\frac{15}4=135$$
Further we have $Y=10\iff X=5$ so that:$$P(Y=10)=P(X=5)$$where the RHS is easy to find.

Comment: I'm sorry, can you please explain how did you find this: Xi = (1/6)Yi+1/6? 
And also, how did you found V(Y)? thank you